# Raspberry Pi not reading SD Card

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os

I've been working on Raspberry Pi 3b+ for quite a few months. I was working on my project and suddenly the Pi shut down automatically. I tried to restart it again but green light was not displayed by Raspberry Pi only red light was being shown.I thought that may be SD card might have been corrupted so I flashed Raspbian OS from Raspberry Pi Imager onto SanDisk 32gb class 10 micro SD card and inserted into the card slot. Then also same error occurred. So I tried again flashed a new image same error. Only red light is on green light doesn't even light up.

So I tried with another SD card same as earlier SD card specs flashed images then too same error. I also fixed the SD card holder of Raspberry Pi maybe because of that the SD card was not getting detected.Also tried different power sources and USB cables.Same problem as before green light doesn't light up.

This seems to be common problem but it is not working on my case. I don't know what else to do. Is there issue with my Pi?

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: I'd suggest that with absolutely no green LED activity, the SD card slot may be out of action - you have a 3b+ - that should boot from USB thumb drive out of the box - try a USB thumb drive - by the way, you didn't mention what the pi displays on your tv/monitor

Comment: Thank u for ur response. To boot rapsberry pi from usb flash drive I should be able to make changes in rapsberry pi dekstop after the raspberry pi boots.But it isn't booting. Monitor gives a complete blank screen

Comment: oh, so it's not even booting from USB? pi 3b+ boots from USB as standard - no need to do anything, if it's a 3b+ ... not a 3B, but a 3b+, it comes to you, ready to boot from USB - so, just "burn" raspberry pi OS onto a USB thumb drive, and you'll be golden

Comment: Still no progress I tried to flashed onto USB flash drive multiple times. It's not booting
Is my Pi broken?

Comment: is it definitely a 3+? Mu guess is, it's broken